# Сервинг во Flask

Tags: python, flask

Есть некоторая модель ML.
Где-то есть Flask. Также Flask есть в папке виртуальной среды virtualenv.

Есть еще код из книжки:

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, flash, jsonify
import numpy as np
import pickle as p
import requests
import json


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/api/', methods=['POST'])
def makecalc():
    data = request.get_json()
    prediction = np.array2string(model.predict(data))
    return jsonify(prediction)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    modelfile = 'model.pickle'
    model = p.load(open(modelfile, 'rb'))
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')



url = 'http://0.0.0.0:5000/api/'

data = []
j_data = json.dumps(data)
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept-Charset': 'UTF-8'}
r = requests.post(url, data=j_data, headers=headers)
print(r, r.text)
```

Вопрос: Как внедрить модель в продукцию на flask?

Comment: `внедрить модель в продукцию на flask` - это нужно расшифровать.

Comment: @RomanKonoval я сам не знаю что это значит. Подозреваю что речь о какой-то контейнеризации или что-то такое. Звучало слово "Сервинг".

Comment: Ну вот вместо `return "Hello, World!"` возвращаете результат, который даёт ваша модель.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почитайте [Руководство по развертыванию моделей машинного обучения в рабочей среде в качестве API с помощью Flask](https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/442918/).
Вам нужно:

- получить в вашем сервере `Flask` данные через `HTTP` запрос
- данные эти нужно предобработать
- подгрузить натренированную заранее ML модель
- "скормить" модели эти данные и получить от неё предсказание
- вернуть предсказание в понятном для передачи по протоколу `HTTP` виде

Если вы делаете `API`, то получаете данные и возвращаете результат в виде `JSON`.

Но вы можете сделать и веб-страничку для запросов, тогда ваш `Flask` сервер должен сначала отрисовывать страничку, на которой можно заполнить форму и сделать к нему запрос уже с параметрами-данными, и тогда вы в ответе уже отрисовываете опять же полноценную веб-страничку с результатами.